# GDB bactrace print weird contents

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, gdb

I have python binded C++ library, and set it to debug build way. When I debug python program with GDB, I did get some useful contents. But there are many weird `@` symbols. Anyone knows about these? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `@@QEAXXW4`/ `@2@@Z`, what are these?

Comment: Is your question about the apparent infinite recursion? Or about the "weird" symbols? If it's about the symbols you don't need that screenshot, just copy-paste one line *as text* and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Function names are mangled in C++ to allow overloading.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for your correction, I will close this question.

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text, cut/paste text instead.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Sorry to forget this. Because this problem is generated from remote device, reconnecting to it is boring so I just paste the image. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment mentioned, it seems to be C++ name mangling. MSVC C++ Mangling rules: https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling